# Undefined variables in PHP after sending data via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, backend

I am trying to send data via Ajax to my php file and process it, I don't know where is the error Ajax seems to be Okay but after receiving data via $_POST in php file but when I am trying to echo my variables I am getting errors.

I am sending data using a POST;

here is my frontend code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- <form id="ArticleEnterForm" method="POST" action="ProcessFormData.php"> -->
    <div id="warningsDiv">
        wowowo
    </div>
    <label id="ArticleTitleLabel">Article title: </label>
    <input id="ArticleTitleInputField" type="text" name="">
    <div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="ArticleiFrame"></iframe>
    <label>Enter article: </label>
    <textarea id="ArticleContentTextArea"></textarea>
    <label id="ArticleFileNameLabel">Enter file name(save as):</label>
    <input id="ArticleFileNameInputField" type="text">
    <button id="SubmitButton"  name="submitButton">Submit</button>
    <!-- </form> -->
    <script>
        function SubmitForm() {
            function CheckFields() {

                var warningsDiv = document.getElementById('warningsDiv');

                var ArticleTitle = document.getElementById('ArticleTitleInputField');
                var ArticleContent = document.getElementById('ArticleContentTextArea');
                var ArticleFileName = document.getElementById('ArticleFileNameInputField');

                if (ArticleTitle.value == "") { warningsDiv.innerHTML += "<strong> Enter article Name </strong>"; } else { return true; }
                if (ArticleContent.value == "") { warningsDiv.innerHTML += "<strong> Enter article content </strong>"; } else { return true; }
                if (ArticleFileName.value == "") { warningsDiv.innerHTML += "<strong> Enter article file name (save as) </strong>"; } else { return true; }

            }

            if (CheckFields == true) {

                var articleTitle = ArticleTitle.value;
                var articleContent = ArticleContent.value;
                var articleFileName = ArticleFileName.value;
            }


            //submitting using POST method
            var sendDataRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            sendDataRequest.open("POST", "ProcessFormData.php", true);
            sendDataRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            sendDataRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (sendDataRequest.readyState === 2) {
                    warningsDiv.innerHTML = "<strong>Loading...</strong>";
                }
                if (sendDataRequest.readyState === 4 && sendDataRequest.status === 200) {
                    console.log("dtatus: " + sendDataRequest.readyState);
                    warningsDiv.innerHTML = sendDataRequest.responseText;

                }
            }
            var dataToSend = "ArticleTitleData=" + articleTitle + "&ArticleContentData=" + articleContent + "&ArticleFileNameData=" + articleFileName;
            sendDataRequest.send(dataToSend);
        }
        var submitButton = document.getElementById('SubmitButton');
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", SubmitForm);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');    //to get errors displayed

$ArticleTitle = "";
$ArticleContent = "";
$ArticleFileName = "";

if(isset($_POST['ArticleTitleData'])){
    $ArticleTitle = $_POST['ArticleTitleData'];
}else {
    echo("no var artn ");
}

echo("data was entered successfully  following data was entered:  Title: " . $ArticleTitle );
?>
```

where is the error in this script.

the response text I am seeing on browser screen is:

data was entered successfully following data was entered: Title: undefined

Comment: `console.log(ArticleTitle)` in js first ands see what it gives you

Comment: @delboy1978uk it is saying Cant find variable.

Comment: Yea, it looks like you're sending it an empty variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I figured out what was the problem 
short answer:
when I was not calling the `CheckFields();` properly
long answer:
Instead of `if(CheckFields() == true){ //something }` I was doing `if(CheckFields == true){ //something }`
I came to know this because when I was submitting the input field empty there was no change in `warningsDiv` as it was supposed to be when `CheckFields();` function is called.

Thanks everyone for helping me...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some of the variables you are using, are undefined in the scope you are trying to use them in:

```
        function CheckFields() {
            // The variables defined with `var` exist in the scope of this function
            var warningsDiv = document.getElementById('warningsDiv');

            var ArticleTitle = document.getElementById('ArticleTitleInputField');
            var ArticleContent = document.getElementById('ArticleContentTextArea');
            var ArticleFileName = document.getElementById('ArticleFileNameInputField');

            if (ArticleTitle.value == "") { warningsDiv.innerHTML += "<strong> Enter article Name </strong>"; } else { return true; }
            if (ArticleContent.value == "") { warningsDiv.innerHTML += "<strong> Enter article content </strong>"; } else { return true; }
            if (ArticleFileName.value == "") { warningsDiv.innerHTML += "<strong> Enter article file name (save as) </strong>"; } else { return true; }

        }

        if (CheckFields == true) {
            // No `ArticleTitle`, etc. here...
            var articleTitle = ArticleTitle.value;
            var articleContent = ArticleContent.value;
            var articleFileName = ArticleFileName.value;
        }
```

Note that you are defining your variables using `var` in the `CheckFields()` function. So the scope of these variables is that function and anything in it, they will not be available outside of the `CheckFields()` function.

To solve that, you can return them from or define them before the function.

For example:

```
        var ArticleTitle = document.getElementById('ArticleTitleInputField');
        var ArticleContent = document.getElementById('ArticleContentTextArea');
        var ArticleFileName = document.getElementById('ArticleFileNameInputField');

        function CheckFields() {

            var warningsDiv = document.getElementById('warningsDiv');

            if (ArticleTitle.value == "") { warningsDiv.innerHTML += "<strong> Enter article Name </strong>"; } else { return true; }
            if (ArticleContent.value == "") { warningsDiv.innerHTML += "<strong> Enter article content </strong>"; } else { return true; }
            if (ArticleFileName.value == "") { warningsDiv.innerHTML += "<strong> Enter article file name (save as) </strong>"; } else { return true; }

        }

        // etc.
```

Note that if you need the `warningsDiv` outside of the function as well, you would need to treat it the same.

Comment: I moved it out of the CheckFields() function I am able to log it but response is same ("undefined").

Comment: @Techguy So what does `dataToSend` contain right before you send it?

Comment: I did console.log(dataToSend);   output was: ArticleTitleData=undefined&ArticleContentData=undefined&ArticleFileNameData=undefined